# Powershell Select-String and then obtain data on returned files

Tags: string, search, powershell, powershell-2.0

I admit I am quite tired today but even that is no excuse for the nightmare i seem to be creating for myself with Powershell at present.

Basically the aim is to search a directory for a string that is contained in some word documents.  Then I need to return the file name, created date and the last write time.  Easy I thought but at some stage I have gone well off track and am still climbing.

What I have done so far is run the search and export the path variable to a text file giving me the path to the files that contain the string.  I have then tried to use a foreach loop to load the contents of the file and run a Get-ChildItem against each entry piped to a Select-Object Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime.  I have finally > this to a text file.  However it now seems to be returing the info for every file in teh directory and not just those that contain the string I am searching for.  I get the feeling I am vastly over complicating this as i tend to with these things.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.doc | Select-String "Shiba" | select-object path > C:\TRCALM\shibapath.txt


$files = get-content C:\TRCALM\shibapath.txt


foreach($i in $files){gci $i | select-object Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime > C:\TRCALM\SHIBADates.txt}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -Include *.doc | Select-String "Shiba"| select-object path )
$k = foreach($i in $files){ (gci $i.Path | select-object Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime) } 
$k > C:\pst\SHIBADates.txt
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that it was because I had not used $i.Path in my command that it was bringing back all the files from the directory?

Comment: Also formatting in the file was not really good if have it on the same line, for me at least